# java listen to ContextRefreshedEvent

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I have a classX in my spring application in which I want to be able to find out if all spring beans have been initialized. To do this, I am trying to listen ContextRefreshedEvent.

So far I have the following code but I am not sure if this is enough.

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent;

public classX implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
       //do something if all apps have initialised
    }
}
```

1. Is this approach correct to find out if all beans have initialsed?
2. What else do I need to do to be able to listen to the ContextRefreshedEvent ? DO I need to register classX somewhere in xml files ?

Comment: Just as a supplement to the answer of Sotirios Delimanolis: if you use Spring Framework 4.2 or above you can simply annotate a method of a managed-bean with `@EventListener` to automatically register an `ApplicationListener` matching the signature of the method. Read more here: https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/11/better-application-events-in-spring-framework-4-2

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A `ContextRefreshEvent` occurs

> when an `ApplicationContext` gets initialized or refreshed.

so you are on the right track.

What you need to do is declare a bean definition for `classX`.

Either with `@Component` and a component scan over the package it's in

```
@Component
public class X implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
       //do something if all apps have initialised
    }
}
```

or with a `<bean>` declaration

```
<bean class="some.pack.X"></bean>
```

Spring will detect that the bean is of type `ApplicationListener` and register it without any further configuration.

Later Spring version support annotation-based event listeners. The [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#context-functionality-events-annotation) states

> As of Spring 4.2, you can register an event listener on any public
>   method of a managed bean by using the `@EventListener` annotation.

Within the `X` class above, you could declare an annotated method like

```
@EventListener
public void onEventWithArg(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
}
```

or even

```
@EventListener(ContextRefreshedEvent.class)
public void onEventWithout() {

}
```

The context will detect this method and register it as a listener for the specified event type.

The documentation goes into way more detail about the full feature set: conditional processing with SpEL expression, async listeners, etc.

---

Just FYI, Java has naming conventions for types, variables, etc. For classes, the convention is to have their names start with an uppercase alphabetic character.

Comment: By the way, "As long as the context has not been closed, a refresh can be triggered multiple times, provided that the chosen ApplicationContext actually supports such "hot" refreshes. "

Comment: I know context initialization but what is mean by `context getting refreshed` ?

Comment: @piechuckerr See [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractApplicationContext.html#refresh--).

Answer (score 15):

### Spring >= 4.2

You can use annotation-driven event listener as below :

```
@Component
public class classX  {

    @EventListener
    public void handleContextRefresh(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {

    }
}
```

the ApplicationListener you want to register is defined in the **signature** of the method.

Comment: Only since spring 4.2

Answer (score 3):

(**ContextRefreshedEvent event**) gets called twice, one in init and secondly after init.

You can use (**ApplicationReadyEvent event**) and call will be made only once after init.

```
public class InvokeCatalogOne implements IInvokeCatalogOne {

    @EventListener
    public void fetchChargeCode(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I will prefer ApplicationReadyEvent. I found ContextRefreshedEvent is called before my http server is started. ApplicationReadyEvent will make sure your application is ready to take request.

```
    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void startApp() {
        LOGGER.info("Application is now ready!");
    }
```