# Start Spring Boot refusing traffic at first

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Right after all the beans are created and started, Spring Boot sets the *LivenessState* to *CORRECT* and *ReadinessState* to *ACCEPTING_TRAFFIC*.

However, after my application starts, it still needs to load a bunch of data on a *ContextRefreshedEvent* event listener.

How do I prevent setting the *ReadinessState* to *ACCEPTING_TRAFFIC* automatically?

Comment: Did you find a good solution?  I thought maybe setting the readiness state to refusing traffic after the application starts up, but not sure how stable that will be.

Comment: @reactive-core I used the solution posted by Poklakni, Spring will wait until all event listeners finish before setting the LivenessState and ReadinessState

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own `HealthIndicator` that marks your app as ready after the data is `loaded`

```java
@Component
public class DataLoadingHealthIndicator implements HealthIndicator {

    private boolean dataLoaded = false;

    @EventListener
    public void handleContextRefresh(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        // Load your data here
        dataLoaded = true;
    }

    @Override
    public Health health() {
        if (dataLoaded) {
            return Health.up().build();
        } else {
            return Health.down().build();
        }
    }
}
```

if you don't want to load the data in the health indicator, you can fire a custom event right after you load the data and listen to that event in your custom health indicator.

more useful info can be found here: [java listen to ContextRefreshedEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20275952/java-listen-to-contextrefreshedevent)